# I am trying to swipe my images in an image gallery.i am trying to do this on this site.( http://klaret.dk/ ) But my swipe function doesnt work

Tags: jquery, wordpress, swipe-gesture

I am trying to swipe my images in an image gallery.i am trying to do this on this site.( http://klaret.dk/ ) But my swipe function doesnt work. here is the code i am using.I have added the jquery library aswell as the jquery mobile ui library. still it doesnt work

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function(){
            alert("here");
            //alert($('.fs_gallery_wrapper').html())
            $(".fs_slide").on("swipe", function() { 
                alert("hello"); 
            });

        });
```

Comment: Any plugin used for image sliding ?

Comment: No. Its a simple gallery used for this. You can check it.  here is the link: ( http://klaret.dk/ )

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this and it worked. Awesome.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("swipeleft",'.fs_gallery_wrapper', function(){
        //alert("here");
      nextSlide();

    });
    $(document).on("swiperight",'.fs_gallery_wrapper', function(){
        //alert("here");
      prevSlide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I also tried this but forgot to add jquery mobile in it.